# Export Google Chart to PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, svg, google-visualization

I am using this gem for my RoR app: [Google Visualr](http://googlevisualr.herokuapp.com/) to generate some charts in my application. So I have code like this in my view:

```
<div id='chart'></div>
<%= render_chart @chart_data, 'chart' %>
```

That renders a [Google Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/) and I have to say it's pretty cool.  However, how can I make a PDF from the chart?  I was using the old Google image Charts and it was pretty easy to render the image to a pdf, but with this SVG I fail to see how to do it.

Any thoughts or recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not using Google Charts but I'm using Highcharts. I've found great success in rendering  charts to pdf using a combination of 2 gems:

wicked_pdf - https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf
and 
wkhtmltopdf-binary - https://github.com/zakird/wkhtmltopdf_binary_gem

The second is the binary dependency for wicked_pdf. It was pretty straight forward to use and it can render your rails view in pdf format. If you plan on deploying on heroku, replace the second gem with:

wkhtmltopdf-heroku - https://github.com/bradphelan/wkhtmltopdf-heroku

Comment: So... I added the wkhtmltopdf-heroku in groups production, but I keep getting: RuntimeError: Location of wkhtmltopdf unknown in "[PROJECT_ROOT]/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wicked_pdf-0.7.9/lib/wicked_pdf.rb, line 22"

Comment: So.. It seems heroku is trying to get the binaries from the development group...?

Comment: @jun im having similar problem, can i get a link which explains your solution better, all i want to do is show my highchart piechart on my pdf

Comment: do you highchart charts scale in the PDF. Are they vector graphics or rastorized?